# What would a Venus sky look like above the cloud tops night and day?

Tags: atmosphere, venus

I know it will likely be a yellow haze at the surface level, but I've seen little info about what a Venus sky looks like above the cloud tops or in the midsts of them.

Will the sky be blue like on earth or yellowish at daytime? Will sunset be reddish as on earth?

How about night, will it be really dark without a moon, or will e.g. Mercury be similar in light strength as the moon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably going to be blue for the exact same reason that Earth's sky is blue, shorter wavelengths of light are scattered more so the scattered light in the atmosphere is biased towards the blue end of the spectrum. Sunsets would also be red for the same reason as on Earth, probably even redder because as the sun sets it would be able to pass through a greater thickness of atmosphere than on Earth (as we are observing from a vantage point above the clouds).

With that said, human color perception is complicated and depends on both the eyes and the brain, the sunlight above the clouds on Venus would be about twice as bright as on Earth, I don't know if that would have an effect on how our eyes perceive the color of the sky, but it could. It would probably still be somewhere between blue and white though.

Comment: This is a good answer, both that Raleigh scattering will happen, and that color perception is a tricky thing.